# How can I redirect a user back to the page he was previously on after he has logged in?

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a user back to the page he was previously on after he has logged in. So I did this in my controller:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
$this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl());
```

However, it seems like `$session->getBeforeAuthUrl()` is always returning `null` and it ends up redirecting to an blank page.

How can I redirect a user back to the page he was previously on after he has logged in?

Comment: You need to set `$session->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());` in `Mage_Customer_AccountController::loginAction()` first. Also see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29580/redirect-user-after-login

Answer (score 1):

Just change the option:

```
System > Config > Customer 
> Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

Comment: But this will affect the global behaviour, wouldn't it? I was hoping that only my module would redirect to where the user came from before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for the login url, it will redirect the user back to the page from where the user has clicked the login link.

```
Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();
```

and modify below settings

```
System -> Configuration -> Customer 
-> Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in -> NO
```

Comment: I tried redirecting to this and I get this error `localhost redirected you too many times.`

Comment: You need not to redirect to this url, above code will generate the login url for the user and using this login user will automatically redirected to the page it was earlier. This code is not for redirection, it was for generating the login link url.

Comment: Somehow, I'm getting "http://localhost/cms/index/noRoute/" from `Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();`
That URL brings me to a 404.